# Pods Error in Xcode - Compile Failed in Swift 5.0 in Some modules

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I have a strange issue when clone the GIT repo and run the cocoa-pod update, it works fine (see the pod file for the config). however when I compile the project on the Xcode it seems to fail some module with some errors, is there anything I am doing wrong here because I am new to X-code dev.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update your socket pod may fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Pod Socket IO Client you're trying to use isn't available on swift 5 means you have to use latest version which is also available on Swift 5.

May fix this issue by removing version # you mention in your Podfile. It should be like this

#Chat Socket API
pod "Socket.IO-Client-Swift" That's it don't need this **,'12.1.3'**